# login failed exception while sending email from gmail SMTP for new gmail accounts

Tags: c#, .net, smtp, google-docs-api, google-authentication

I am facing a unique issue while using google api for google documents or sending emails from smtp.google.com, i am able to send emails using my old gmail id but now i am supposed to use some new gmail accounts and unfortunately i am getting exception of authentication failed.

Is their any setting which we have to make to enable the services of Google API.

My code is below, its working for some account and failed for some(new accounts created in last 6 months)

```
 public static void Sendemail(string from, string to, string subject, string message, string password, string smtpUrl,int port,string userName,bool ssl)
        {
            try
            {

                System.Net.Mail.MailMessage MyMailMessage = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(from, to, subject, message);

                MyMailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

                //Proper Authentication Details need to be passed when sending email from gmail
                System.Net.NetworkCredential mailAuthentication = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(userName, password);

                //Smtp Mail server of Gmail is "smpt.gmail.com" and it uses port no. 587
                //For different server like yahoo this details changes and you can
                //get it from respective server.
                System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient mailClient = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);

                //Enable SSL
                mailClient.EnableSsl = true;


                mailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

                mailClient.Credentials = mailAuthentication;

                mailClient.Send(MyMailMessage);
            }
            catch
            {
            }

        }
```